# jStorage on android web view

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, android-webview, local-storage

I'm developping a mobile application, which should connect to a web server. The application is written with jQM and simply imported in an android web view. The problem is that I want to save a specific personal information in the local storage using the jStorage plugin and later send it to the server. This works perfectly when I test it on my computer, but when I try it on the device with the web view, it does not work - it sends null.
So I'd like to know if it's possible to use local storage on an imported web view or should I look for another solution. I didn't use cookies, because I had problems with the library and then it worked pretty well locally with browser's local storage.

Here is my Activity code:

```
private WebView mWebView;
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      mWebView = new WebView(this);
      WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
      webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
      webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true); 
      mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/accents.html");

      mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() { 
            public void onExceededDatabaseQuota(String url, String databaseIdentifier, long currentQuota, long estimatedSize, long totalUsedQuota, WebStorage.QuotaUpdater quotaUpdater) { 
                    quotaUpdater.updateQuota(5 * 1024 * 1024); 
                } 
            }); 

      this.setContentView(mWebView);
  }
```

And here is the js sample:

```
$.jStorage.set("access_token", data.access_token);
$.jStorage.set("refresh_token", data.refresh_token);
$.jStorage.set("logged", true);
```

After that

```
access_token = $.jStorage.get("access_token");
refresh_token = $.jStorage.get("refresh_token");
```

Sets both values to `null`